I need a simple solution to check id an index is outside my 2d list
I have recently challenged myself to make a maze generator using depth first search (with which I have zero experience) and I have a function which will be called a bunch for checking if the neighbors of a point in a 2d list are vallid and unvisited. I have my own system for notation of  connections in a 2d network so just know that 0s  unvisited locations.
def checkNeighbors(map,x,y):
    left = (-1,0)
    right = (1,0)
    up = (0,1)
    down = (0,-1)

    clearDirs = []

    if (map[y][x-1] == 0) and (map[y][x-1] != None):
        clearDirs.append(left)
    if (map[y][x+1] == 0) and (map[y][x+1] != None):
        clearDirs.append(right)
    if (map[y+1][x] == 0) and (map[y+1][x] != None):
        clearDirs.append(up)
    if (map[y-1][x] == 0) and (map[y-1][x] != None):
        clearDirs.append(down)

    return clearDirs

I tried playing around with the parameters but couldn't think of any property which and I used a print function on clearDirs to give me an idea as to whats happening.
I would also like to ask that you don't tell me solutions to any other parts of the depth first search as I need to try before I improve, thanks!

I'd recommend renaming map to something else. map is the name of a builtin Python function; reusing names like that can make things a little confusing.

len(mylist) will tell you the valid indexes for the list.  If a list contains, say, six elements, then the valid indexes for that list are 0-5.

You can use the length of map to determine whether an index is out of range. An index i will be in range for a list l if 0 <= i < len(l), so you can use that formula to write a quick function that checks if (x, y) is within your map:
def isValidPoint(map, x, y):
    yInBounds = (0 <= y < len(map))

    if not yInBounds:
        return False

    xInBounds = (0 <= x < len(map[y]))
    return xInBounds

You can then call this function whenever you want to check whether a coordinate is inside your 2D list.
This isn't the shortest possible implementation, but I like it because it works on jagged 2D lists as well as rectangular ones.
PS: I used map to represent the grid since that's what you did, but it's probably not the best name for this variable since map() is already a builtin Python function.
